# Javascript child_process.spawn docker Error

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, child-process

I'm spinning up a rabbitmq container successfully from cmd like so

```
docker run -d  --rm -p 5672:5672 --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3
```

but when im trying to spin it up using

```
child_process.spawn('docker',['run','-d','--rm','-p 5672:5672', '--hostname my-rabbit','--name some-rabbit','rabbitmq:3'],{ stdio: 'inherit' });
```

I am getting unknown flag:

```
--hostname my-rabbit
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate your attributes and values:

```
child_process.spawn('docker',['run', '-d', '--rm', '-p', '5672:5672', '--hostname', 'my-rabbit', '--name', 'some-rabbit', 'rabbitmq:3'],{ stdio: 'inherit' });
```